# How to make more memory available to a .Net application?

Tags: .net, memory, out-of-memory

I have to deal with a huge data structure and get `System.OutOfMemoryException` extremely quickly.

In Java I can easily adjust how much memory is my application allowed to consume and set it to up to 2 GiB. Is the same possible in .Net?

I've got 4 GiB of RAM and 32-bit Windows on my dev. machine (and am willing to dedicate at least 2 GiBs to the application) and 16 GiB of RAM and 64-bit Windows on the server (and am willing to dedicate up to 10 GiBs to the application).

Comment: Take a look at the Memory Mapped Files

Comment: There is no config for that in .NET, an app always gets the entire available virtual memory space.  You'll need the 64-bit version of Windows to get more.  Forty bucks solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will hit a 2GB of virtual memory with your application when you build it on 32bit.

There's no way to avoid that.

Do you have the same issue on the 64bit machine? Do you run a 32bit build there? An AnyCPU (which will default to 32bit). Try to create a 64bit app and run it there.

Comment: I haven't tried the 64-bit system yet but I get the exception so quickly that I doubt it hits 2 GiBs on my 32-bit system.

Comment: Ivan, please measure your memory usage, and give us some numbers/graphs. We cannot guess :)

Comment: I can't test the things right now so let's go theory: if you mean that a 64-bit .Net application can use all the memory installed on a 64-bit system by default then please add this statement into the answer text. If there is an option to limit an application memory consumption - please mention it as well, if there is not - state this. I shall accept your answer then. Thanks in advance.